# What the anonymous to registered user ratio at stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, users

I would like to know what the ratio between anonymous and registered (logged in) users is for stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember hearing on the podcast, well over 90% of the traffic on SO is from anonymous users; however, I could be wrong :)

Comment: That means caching the question detail pages should work extremely well.

Comment: They already do that. They cache almost everything.

Comment: It does. You really should listen to the podcast (the topic is discussed in episode 67 & 68, I believe), it has a wealth of information on this subject.

Comment: Often times the answer to a programming question I enter into a browser directs me to stackoverflow. If I am not logged in, I count as an anonymous user, if I am, how am I counted?